# Extract only relevant information from list of lists in python

Tags: python

I have a list which has sub-lists of strings.

**Like**:

```
info = [['Price: 5000', 'In warranty', 'Weight: 8 kg'], 

['Refundable', 'Price: 2800', 'Weight: 5.5 kg', 'Extra battery power'], 

['Price: 9000', 'Non-exchangeable', 'Weight: 8 kg', 'High-Quality']..]
```

Every sub-list has some extra strings which are irrelevant. I only need exact 5 values in sub-lists that best describe info of the product and each of these 5 values have their own keywords.

**What is the way to extract useful strings from sub-lists using keywords & discard the rest?** In above example I want to keep only '**Price**', '**Weight**'.

Comment: How do you define "useful"?

Comment: I have fixed keywords - like 'Price', 'Weight'

Comment: do you want to access price and weight or remove non-useful strings?

Comment: In that case you can loop through the info list and check to see if your keywords exist within the string using the `in` keyword.

Comment: Would this be better served with a dictionary rather than a list?

Comment: Yeah if the keys are Known and pre-decided a dictionary key value pair would serve better than a string key value pair

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `in` keyword can be used to see if a string (or list) contains another string.
You can use the `any` keyword to check multiple items at once.

```py
info = [
    ['Price: 5000', 'In warranty', 'Weight: 8 kg'], 
    ['Refundable', 'Price: 2800', 'Weight: 5.5 kg', 'Extra battery power'], 
    ['Price: 9000', 'Non-exchangeable', 'Weight: 8 kg', 'High-Quality']
]

keywords = ['Price', 'Weight']

for item in info:
    print([x for x in item if any(kw in x for kw in keywords)])
```

**Output:**

```py
['Price: 5000', 'Weight: 8 kg']
['Price: 2800', 'Weight: 5.5 kg']
['Price: 9000', 'Weight: 8 kg']
```

A cleaner format for this data might be using a dictionary.

```py
info = [
    {
        'Price': 5000, 
        'Weight': '8 kg',
        'Attributes': ['In warranty'] 
    },
    {
        'Price': 2800, 
        'Weight': '5.5 kg',
        'Attributes': ['Refundable', 'Extra battery power'] 
    },
    {
        'Price': 9000, 
        'Weight': '8 kg',
        'Attributes': ['Non-exchangeable', 'High-Quality'] 
    }
]

keywords = ['Price', 'Weight']

info_filterd = [{k: v for k, v in item.items() if k in keywords} for item in info]
print(info_filterd)
```

**Output:**

```py
[
    {
        "Price": 5000,
        "Weight": "8 kg"
    },
    {
        "Price": 2800,
        "Weight": "5.5 kg"
    },
    {
        "Price": 9000,
        "Weight": "8 kg"
    }
]
```

Comment: Consider making `keywords` a set so using `in` is `O(1)` rather than `O(n)`, makes a difference at least in your second solution.

Comment: That is a good point but OP only has 5 keywords and I think set syntax might not be as familiar to new python users.

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly and was easy to understand!

Answer (score 1):

One-liner using functional programming (map, filter and any)

```
info = [
    ['Price: 5000', 'In warranty', 'Weight: 8 kg'], 
    ['Refundable', 'Price: 2800', 'Weight: 5.5 kg', 'Extra battery power'], 
    ['Price: 9000', 'Non-exchangeable', 'Weight: 8 kg', 'High-Quality']
]

keywords = ['Price', 'Weight']

l = map(lambda sub_list: list(filter(lambda element: any(map(lambda keyword: keyword in element, keywords)), sub_list)), info)

print(list(l))
```

Output:

```
[['Price: 5000', 'Weight: 8 kg'], ['Price: 2800', 'Weight: 5.5 kg'], ['Price: 9000', 'Weight: 8 kg']]
```

### Explanation of each part of the one-liner

```
map(lambda sub_list: list(filter(lambda element: any(map(lambda keyword: keyword in element, keywords)), sub_list)), info)
```

Iterate over all elements of info applaying the lambda function

```
filter(lambda element: any(map(lambda keyword: keyword in element, keywords)), sub_list)
```

Of all values of sub_list, get the ones (filter) that contains at least one keyword

```
any(map(lambda keyword: keyword in element, keywords))
```

This will return true or false if any of the keyword in keywords is present in element

Note: list() are used to expand the generators

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution using `difflib.SequenceMatcher` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher)). However, some tweaking with ratio may be needed:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

info = [['Price: 5000', 'In warranty', 'Weight: 8 kg'],
        ['Refundable', 'Price: 2800', 'Weight: 5.5 kg', 'Extra battery power'],
        ['Price: 9000', 'Non-exchangeable', 'Weight: 8 kg', 'High-Quality']]

keywords = ['Price', 'Weight']

out = []
for i in info:
    out.append([])
    for item in i:
        if any(SequenceMatcher(None, item.lower(), kw.lower()).ratio() > 0.5 for kw in keywords):
            out[-1].append(item)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
[['Price: 5000', 'Weight: 8 kg'],
 ['Price: 2800', 'Weight: 5.5 kg'],
 ['Price: 9000', 'Weight: 8 kg']]
```

Answer (score -1):

Regex can help.

```
import re

info = [['Price: 5000', 'In warranty', 'Weight: 8 kg'], 

['Refundable', 'Price: 2800', 'Weight: 5.5 kg', 'Extra battery power'], 

['Price: 9000', 'Non-exchangeable', 'Weight: 8 kg', 'High-Quality']]
out=[]
for i in info:
    li=[]
    for j in i:
        if(re.match('(?:Price)|(?:Weight).*',j)):
            li.append(j)
    out.append(li)

print(out)
```

output from this

```
[['Price: 5000', 'Weight: 8 kg'], ['Price: 2800', 'Weight: 5.5 kg'], ['Price: 9000', 'Weight: 8 kg']]
```